# Get the name of 2 users ID

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables one of them contains 2 users ID for the creator and manager

first table

```
creator_id  manager_id  status
-----------------------------
   2      -    1    -  closed
```

second table

```
user_id  user_name
-------------------
  1     |   Tom
  2     |   George
```

I need to get the data like below

```
creator_id| manager_id  status
-----------------------------
   George |   Tom     | closed
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Go for it!

Comment: You'd need to use joins - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: `SELECT try FROM yourself WHERE task = 'get user ids'` - you can do it! :) If you get stuck, we can help you.

Comment: @JessicaPartridge It seems like professional rivalry to me, but all the same, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
select st.user_name as creator_id, sst.user_name as manager_id, ft.status 
from first_table ft 
join second_table st on ft.creator_id= st.user_id 
join second_table sst on ft.manager_id= sst.user_id;
```